# SQL Query to count Unique records ignoring sub string

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have table which have 10 records. Which are as shown below.

```
Data Column

100-1
100-2
100-3
101-1
101-2
102-75
102-76
104-1
104-2
105-8

Select count(1) from table;
```

I am running query to get count which is off course 10, but i want to get count of elements ignoring whatever after "-" sign. So in this case answer of distinct count should be 5 not 10. Any idea which function can help. I am using mySql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `substring_index()` to extract everything before the first hyphen:

```
select count(distinct substring_index(col, '-', 1))
from t;
```